# Meaning of "She denied prior knowledge of the meeting."

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense-agreement

I didn't understand what the sentence "She denied prior knowledge of the meeting." means exactly. The possible meanings to me;

1) She refused that she had some information about the meeting.

2) She refused to get information prior to the meeting.

What is the exact meaning of the sentence and why?

And If the first is true option, Can I write the sentence as "She refused that she had had some information about the meeting that was held." to emphasize that the meeting was held after she got information?

Answer (score 1):

(There is no other person implied in this sentence, so I don't know who "he" is supposed to refer to. And "refused" cannot be used in that way.)

A paraphrase would be "she denied having known about the meeting in advance".

Comment: I made a mistake paraphrasing the sentence and edited the question. Please take the last edit into consideration.

Comment: @over_twenty_five your paraphrase is still wrong, the information she is denying having is even knowing the meeting happened

Comment: @WendyG so, the sentence is not about the content of the meeting. She didn't even know the meeting held.

Comment: @over_twenty_five she is saying "She didn't even know the meeting held", but we have no evidence of the truth of that statement, this wording is often used when there is some doubt

Comment: But that isn't right either. She isn't saying she didn't know the meeting was held. She's saying she didn't know *in advance*.